# How to make angular find imports automatically in vs code

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a angular project generated with nrwl/nx, I generated an model folder manually, but if I try to import something from it I have to do it manually. Is there anyway to make a file where I can put the path to my models and it will automatically be found?

I looked a bit and found this in my tsconfig.base.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@moniesta-admin/auth-lib": ["libs/auth-lib/src/index.ts"],
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}
```

I tried to add it like my auth-lib folder but that does not work either. This is how the index.ts of auth-lib looks:

```
export * from './lib/auth-lib.module';
```

EDIT:

I tried to add my model like this:

```
"@moniesta-admin/model": ["model/index.ts"],
```

this is how the index.ts looks:

```
export * from '../models/*'
```

but this gives me the following error:
the typedeclaration or module was not found

EDIT v2:

[image: folder part1]

[image: folder 2]

Command is the following:
ng g @nrwl/angular:lib

Comment: did u restart ur ts server? How did u generate the new lib? Please show what u did. Exactly Nrwlx is complex.

Comment: I am pretty new to be honest. How do I restart the ts server? I just generated the lib with the command ng g @nrwl/angular:lib my-lib. The model was generated manually with right click

Comment: mac or windows? on Mac its shift + command + p, then type ts there should show a command restart ts server. Also if u generate the lib with the proper command the schematic should handle everything necessary for you, like adding it to your paths object etc.

Comment: I have a windows pc

Comment: ctrl + shift + p then. If this doest help please show everything u have there.

Comment: and please show how exactly u tried to add it to the paths object

Comment: What do you mean with everything? WHich file do you need

Comment: I will edit my answer and show you how I tried adding it

Comment: the directory structure you have seems off, could u pass a screenshot how your directory tree looks like?

Comment: You mean a screenshot from visual studio? Or with a command?

Comment: scrrenshot from vs code with everything expanded, that is of interest. Also put the command u used to generate the lib

Comment: I did what you asked posted the screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242416/discussion-between-sagat-and-natyus).